# How to get the last month data and month to date data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Need help in writing the query to get the last month data as well as month to date data.

If today's date is Mar 23 2011, I need to retrieve the data from last month and the data till todays date(means Mar 23 2011).

If date is Apr 3 2011, data should consists of March month data and the data till Apr 3rd 2011.

Thanks,

Shahsra

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Today including time info  : getdate()
Today without time info    : DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
Tomorrow without time info : DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 1)
Beginning of current month : DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
Beginning of last month    : DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0)
```

so most likely

```
WHERE dateColumn >= DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0)
  AND dateColumn <  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()), 1)
```

Comment: Nice, I like the datediff solution.

Answer (score 4):

Step back one month, subtract the number of days to the current date, and add one day.

```
WHERE  
  DateField <= GetDate() AND
  DateField >= DateAdd(
      mm, 
      -1, 
      DateAdd(dd, -1*DatePart(dd, GetDate())+1, GetDate())
  )
```

To remove the time quickly, you can use this
Cast( Floor( Cast( GETDATE() AS FLOAT ) ) AS DATETIME )

So the second part would be (without time)

```
DateField >= Cast( Floor( Cast( (DateAdd(
          mm, 
          -1, 
          DateAdd(dd, -1*DatePart(dd, GetDate())+1, GetDate())
      )) AS FLOAT ) ) AS DATETIME )
```

Comment: inexact - the 2nd one gives "2011-02-01 10:55:49.160"

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Column1, Column2 From Table1
Where DateColumn <= GetDate() AND 
DateColumn >= DATEADD(dd, - (DAY(DATEADD(mm, 1, GetDate())) - 1), DATEADD(mm, - 1, GetDate()))
```

Edit: +1 to Russel Steen. I was posting mine before I knew he had posted.

Answer (score 0):

[Very helpful page](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/robyn-pages-sql-server-datetime-workbench/)

```
declare @d datetime = '2011-04-03';

declare @startDate datetime;
select @startDate =
   CAST('01 '+ RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(11),DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@d),113),8) AS datetime);
select @startDate;
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me the link. Really its very useful.