# How to get last month datas display in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i´m writing a query ! i get the last month, but with the out not work

So I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `salarystaff` WHERE MONTH(date)=DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())
```

output
 i want to display all data in last month

Comment: `but with the out not work` means are you getting any error?

Comment: #1305 - FUNCTION employee.DATEADD does not exist

Comment: Well in that case your first port of call should have been the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query as follows :

```
SELECT * FROM `salarystaff` WHERE MONTH(date_column)=MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE  MONTH(date_created) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL MONTH() returns the MONTH for the date within a range of 1 to 12 ( January to December)
>   [image]

```
Beginning of current month : DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
Beginning of last month    : DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0)

Your sql will be: 
SELECT * FROM XXXX
WHERE date>= DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0)
and date< DATEADD(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

This link will help you
[How to get the last month data and month to date data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412019/how-to-get-the-last-month-data-and-month-to-date-data)