# how to get value from specific month in codeigniter, get value of last month only

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image]

How do I get last month salary, if last month salary was negative then I want to subtract last month negative salary from current month payment? like in pic, mar salary is-32000 so when I pay for April I want to subtract -32000 from April payment

```
    <form role="form"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/payroll/get_payment/<?php
            if (!empty($check_salary_payment->salary_payment_id)) {
                echo $check_salary_payment->salary_payment_id;
            }
            ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-groups-bordered">
                <div class="col-sm-3" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0">        
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="panel panel-primary fees_payment">
                            <!-- Default panel contents -->
                            <div class="panel-heading" >
                                <div class="panel-title">
                                    <strong>Payment For <?php echo date('F,Y', strtotime($payment_date)) ?></strong>                                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>                                                                                                
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="">
                                    <label class="control-label" >Gross Salary </label>
                                    <input type="text" name="house_rent_allowance" disabled  value="<?php
                                    echo $gross = $emp_salary_info->basic_salary + $emp_salary_info->house_rent_allowance + $emp_salary_info->medical_allowance + $emp_salary_info->special_allowance + $emp_salary_info->fuel_allowance + $emp_salary_info->phone_bill_allowance + $emp_salary_info->other_allowance;
                                    ?>"  class="salary form-control">
                                </div>                            
                                <div class="">
                                    <label class="control-label" >Total Deduction </label>
                                    <input type="text" name="other_allowance" disabled  value="<?php
                                    echo $deduction = $emp_salary_info->tax_deduction + $emp_salary_info->provident_fund + $emp_salary_info->other_deduction;
                                    ?>"  class="salary form-control">
                                </div>

                                <div class="">
                                    <?php

                                         $yourDate = date("Y-m", strtotime($payment_date. " -1 months")); // substract 1 month from that date and converting it into timestamp
                                         echo $yourDate;
                                         ?>

                                         <?php
                                        if (!empty($payment_history)): foreach ($payment_history as $v_payment_history) :
                                                ?>

                                                <?php 
                                                      if ((date('F-Y', strtotime($v_payment_history->payment_fo_month == $yourDate ))) && ($v_payment_history->payment_amount < 0 )) 
                                                      {
                                                         echo $negative_payment = $v_payment_history->payment_amount;
                                                } ?>
                                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>


                                   </div>



                                <div class="">

                                    <label class="control-label" >Net Salary </label>
                                    <input type="text" id="net_salary" name="other_allowance" disabled  value="<?php
                                    if (isset($_POST['security_deposit'])) {

                                    echo $net_salary = $emp_salary_info->basic_salary / 2;
                                    }


                                    else {





                                                echo $net_salary = $gross - $deduction;
                                    }


                                    ?>"  class="salary form-control">
                                </div>

                                <?php if (isset($_POST['security_deposit'])) : ?> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="security_deposit" id="security_deposit" value="<?php echo $net_salary = $emp_salary_info->basic_salary / 2; ?>" class="salary form-control">


                                 <?php endif; ?>


                                <?php if (!empty($emp_salary_info->security_deposit)): ?>
                                 <div class="">
                                    <label class="control-label" >Security Deposited </label>

                                    <input type="text" id="security_deposit1" name="security_deposit1" disabled  value="<?php
                                    echo $security =  $emp_salary_info->security_deposit;
                                    ?>"  class="salary form-control">
                                </div>
                                  <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php if (!empty($award_info)): foreach ($award_info as $v_award_info) : ?>
                                        <?php if (!empty($v_award_info->award_amount)): ?>
                                            <div class="">
                                                <label class="control-label" > Advance Salary <small>( <?php echo $v_award_info->award_name; ?> )</small> </label>
                                                <input type="text" name="award_amount" id="award_amount" disabled  value="<?php echo $v_award_info->award_amount; ?>"  class="salary form-control">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="award[]" value="<?php echo $v_award_info->award_amount; ?>"  class="salary form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>                                
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
<div class="">
                                    <label class="control-label" >Incentive</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="incentive" id="incentive" value="<?php
                                    if (!empty($check_salary_payment->incentive)) {
                                        echo $check_salary_payment->incentive;
                                    }
                                    ?>"  class="salary form-control">
                                </div>


                                <div class="">
                                    <label class="control-label" >Fine Deduction </label>
                                    <input type="text" name="fine_deduction" id="fine_deduction" value="<?php
                                    if (!empty($check_salary_payment->fine_deduction)) {
                                        echo $check_salary_payment->fine_deduction;
                                    }
                                    ?>"  class="salary form-control">
                                </div>



                                <div class="">
                                    <label class="control-label" ><strong>Payment Amount </strong></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="payment_amount" id="payment_amount" value="<?php echo $net_salary; ?>"  class="salary form-control">
                                </div>
                                <!-- Hidden Employee Id -->
                                <input type="hidden" id="employee_id" name="employee_id" value="<?php echo $emp_salary_info->employee_id; ?>"  class="salary form-control">                               
                                <input type="hidden"  name="payment_for_month" value="<?php
                                if (!empty($payment_date)) {
                                    echo $payment_date;
                                }
                                ?>"  class="salary form-control">                               
                                <div class=""><!-- Payment Type -->
                                    <label class="control-label" >Payment Type <span class="required"> *</span></label>                                               
                                    <select name="payment_type" class="form-control col-sm-5" onchange="get_payment_value(this.value)" >
                                        <option value="" >Select Payment Type...</option>                                            
                                        <option value="Cash Payment" <?php
                                        if (!empty($check_salary_payment->payment_type)) {
                                            echo $check_salary_payment->payment_type == 'Cash Payment' ? 'selected' : '';
                                        }
                                        ?>>Cash Payment</option>                                            
                                        <option value="Cheque Payment" <?php
                                        if (!empty($check_salary_payment->payment_type)) {
                                            echo $check_salary_payment->payment_type == 'Cheque Payment' ? 'selected' : '';
                                        }
                                        ?>>Cheque Payment</option>                                            
                                        <option value="Bank Account" <?php
                                        if (!empty($check_salary_payment->payment_type)) {
                                            echo $check_salary_payment->payment_type == 'Bank Account' ? 'selected' : '';
                                        }
                                        ?>>Bank Account</option>                                                                                                                                         
                                    </select>                                                 
                                </div><!-- Payment Type -->                                  
                                <div class="">
                                    <label class="control-label" >Comments </label>
                                    <input type="text" name="comments" value="<?php
                                    if (!empty($check_salary_payment->comments)) {
                                        echo $check_salary_payment->comments;
                                    }
                                    ?>"  class="salary form-control">
                                </div>                                
                                <div class="form-group margin"> 
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <button type="submit" name="sbtn" value="1" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                
                        </div>                                
                    </div>                                
                </div><!--************ Fees payment End ***********-->
            </form>
```

I have tried this code, but this code show negative salary every time, I want to get negative salary only the next month. like in the image if negatively is in March then I want to show it only when I give salary for April. but this code show even when I select may June or any month

```
<div class="">
    <?php
    $yourDate = date("Y-m", strtotime($payment_date . " -1 months")); // substract 1 month from that date and converting it into timestamp
    echo $yourDate;
    ?>

    <?php if (!empty($payment_history)): foreach ($payment_history as $v_payment_history) : ?>
        <?php
        if ((date('F-Y', strtotime($v_payment_history->payment_fo_month == $yourDate))) && ($v_payment_history->payment_amount < 0 )) {
            echo $negative_payment = $v_payment_history->payment_amount;
        }
        ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: if($last_month_salary < 0){  $current_month_salary = $current_month_salary - $last_month_salary}

Comment: problem is how to get last month salary

Comment: You can use SQL queries to get salaries of current and one month before current month. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412019/how-to-get-the-last-month-data-and-month-to-date-data